# Same code, errors when vector is changed to unordered_set

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, compiler-errors, set

I have a class like:

```
class VectorAttrIterator : public AttrIterator {
    vector<AttrValue>* values;
    vector<AttrValue>::iterator it;
public:
    VectorAttrIterator(vector<AttrValue>* _values) : values(_values) {
        it = (*values).begin();
    };

    bool hasNext() {
        return it != (*values).end();
    };

    AttrValue next() {
        int ret = (*it);
        it++;
        return ret;
    };

    ~VectorAttrIterator() {
        delete values;
    };
};
```

It works. Then I wanted to do something similar just for `unordered_set`:

```
class UnorderedSetAttrIterator : public AttrIterator {
    unordered_set<AttrValue>* values;
    unordered_set<AttrValue>::iterator it;
public:
    UnorderedSetAttrIterator(vector<AttrValue>* _values) : values(_values) {
        it = (*values).begin();
    };

    bool hasNext() {
        return it != (*values).end();
    };

    AttrValue next() {
        int ret = (*it);
        it++;
        return ret;
    };

    ~UnorderedSetAttrIterator() {
        delete values;
    };
};
```

The only changes are `vector` is changed to `unordered_set` and class renaming. But I get errors like:

```
Error   42  error C2065: 'values' : undeclared identifier   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   40
Error   43  error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union  h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   40
Error   44  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'std::tr1::unordered_set<_Kty> *' h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   39
Error   45  error C2439: 'UnorderedSetAttrIterator::values' : member could not be initialized   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   39
Error   46  error C2065: 'it' : undeclared identifier   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   44
Error   47  error C2065: 'values' : undeclared identifier   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   44
Error   48  error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union    h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   44
Error   49  error C2065: 'it' : undeclared identifier   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   48
Error   50  error C2065: 'it' : undeclared identifier   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   49
Error   51  error C2065: 'values' : undeclared identifier   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\includes\iterator.h   54
```

Whats wrong? Why is values undeclared? **[Full Source](http://pastie.org/7161606#7)**

Comment: Do you have an `#include <unordered_set>` as well as an `#include <vector>`?

Comment: @AndyProwl This is how to solve C++ problems: `#include <andyprowl> using namespace magic;` :P

Comment: @H2CO3: lol, you're really praising me more than I deserve ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl Just seen you again, super fast. (To be fair, I can do this sometimes too, but that's not a pattern :D )

Comment: The original didn't even have `#include <vector>`, but I added it will `#include <unordered_set>` but I still got the same thing ...

Comment: Ahh ... my bad ... `UnorderedSetAttrIterator(vector<AttrValue>* _values)`: an unordered_set should be passed

Comment: Oh, you found it while I was typing my answer. :)

Comment: @DanielFrey, its OK, now I can close this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this line is this problem:

```
UnorderedSetAttrIterator(vector<AttrValue>* _values) : values(_values) {
```

Have you forgotten to change the parameter type from `vector` to `unordered_set`?